# linear of Quadratic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The graph of y=f(x), where f is a function, goes through the points (0,1), (3,8), and (6,9).  Which of the following points could also lie on the graph of y=f(x)?
a) (6,3)  b) (3,9)  c)(5,1)  d) )0,5)

I entered the x values on both a linear(a line) and a quadratic(parabola) function but could not find the answer.  Hope someone can help me out.  Thanks.

Comment: Without further context, we know absolutely nothing about $f(x)$ except that it is a function.  A function can only have at most one output for each input.  Since we are told that $f(3)=8$ it is impossible for $f(3)$ to also equal nine.  That rules out option $b$.  Similarly we can rule out other options.  We are told nothing about how $f$ acts on $5$ however, so unless we are told specifically that $f$ must be a polynomial of some type we have no way of knowing what $f(5)$ could be equal to and all outputs are technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is to test your understanding of what a function is; you need not think too much into it. Recall that a function is defined as having only one "output" per "input" value. i.e. $f(a) = b$ and $f(a) = c$ if and only if $b = c$. So out of the given points none but c) $(5,1)$ can also lie on the graph of your function. This is because the rest of them have the same $x$ value as points that have already been mapped.